# How to encode json data for database storage in MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

I have a javascript rich page that is passing a large JSON formatted to php to be put in a MySQL database. The data in the JSON includes user submitted strings, and will include strings containing basic html (`<a>`, `<strong>` etc.).

The issue I am having is when a string containing a `'` quotation mark is escaped, I cannot strip the slashes, leading to compounding escapes like

```
<a href=\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'example.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'></a>
```

Every time the user saves this is compounded, severely bloating the database field.

My string conversion to insert data into MySQL is :

```
$correspondenceArray = base64_encode(json_encode($_POST['saveArray']['correspondenceObject']));
```

And to get data back is:

```
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

$correspondenceJSON = stripslashes_deep(json_decode(base64_decode($resultArray['correspondence_array']), true));
```

From what I have done my intent is to strip the slashes on the data coming out of the database so the javascript has the unescaped data

**Edit**

I realise `json_encode($a,JSON_HEX_QUOT)` would possibly help, but the server I'm running has PHP 5.2.16 so that feature isn't available)

Comment: Do you have `magic_quotes_gpc()` turned on? Those'll litter slashes all over your data, and the option should be turned OFF.

Comment: Ah no that is turned on. Hmm if I turn this off am I likely to have knock on effects elsewhere?

Comment: You probably want to use mysql_real_escape_string() in your queries when you turn this off to avoid nasty injections, but @Marc B is right, you should turn it off (it's deprecated in PHP 5.3).

Comment: @Capsule Luckily I have already been using `mysql_real_escape_string()` so it should be a fairly safe switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't use string-generation for SQL.**

If placeholders are used there will *no problem* (with storage) and *no magic escaping is required*. Just store it as VARCHAR type. Done and done.

Sanitization for output (*and* during input) should likewise be done using the appropriate libraries -- there are *two different operations*; however, this is a separate issue than storage.

**Edit**

See [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) as one prepared-statement (read: placeholder) implementation. Others may exist (I do not use PHP, but feel obligated to correct the perpetuation of design mistakes relating to manually built string-based SQL queries.)

> > The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this. **If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur** (however, if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible).

Sounds too-good-to-be-true. Now *quit using string-generated statements*. Please.

Happy coding.

Comment: The issue is the object that I am encoding is a a very deep multi-dimensional array (currently up to 5 layers deep) and completely dynamic.

Comment: @Zak Henry This does not change my answer. JSON is text. **Text can be safely stored in a database without "escaping"** if *placeholders* are used in the SQL statements (aka "prepared statements"). Please see: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php or similar -- bad designs must die. Using prepared statements can also -- in theory (depending upon a number of factors including back-end, adapter, and usage-patterns) -- improve performance significantly.

Comment: Unfortunately PDO looks like it uses some stupid implementation with references to variables -- but in any case it goes from a *bad approach* to an *acceptable approach*.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your answer. I have never heard of prepared statements. I will look into it

Comment: @pst Ok, I have implemented PDO and it solves my problem. Answer accepted, thankyou! Now you have shown me this I want to go through all my previous queries and update them >.> grrr